# Syntax to get the value of environment variable in Kconfig file

Tags: linux-kernel

Can anyone provide me the syntax of obtaining the value of environment variable in Kconfig file?

Based on the value of environment variable I need to conditionally source another Kconfig file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [the kconfig docs](http://kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/kconfig-language.txt):

```
<expr> ::= <symbol>                             (1)
           <symbol> '=' <symbol>                (2)
           <symbol> '!=' <symbol>               (3)
           '(' <expr> ')'                       (4)
           '!' <expr>                           (5)
           <expr> '&&' <expr>                   (6)
           <expr> '||' <expr>                   (7)


- misc options: "option" <symbol>[=<value>]

  - "env"=<value>
  This imports the environment variable into Kconfig.

if:

    "if" <expr>
    <if block>
    "endif"

This defines an if block. The dependency expression <expr> is appended
to all enclosed menu entries.

source:

    "source" <prompt>

This reads the specified configuration file. This file is always parsed.
```

So I'd try

```
option env="YOURVAR"
if YOURVAR=foo
    source "somefile"
endif
if YOURVAR!=foo
    source "someotherfile"
endif
```

Answer (score 7):

You will need to capture the value of the environment variable in a config symbol using 'option env', like in the following:

```
config ENV_VAR
    string
    option env="ENV_VAR"

if ENV_VAR = "foo"
source "foo_file"
endif
```

As a side note, $-references in 'source' statements refer to config variables, not to environment variables. You can't do something like

```
source "foo/$ENV_VAR/Kconfig"
```

You will instead need to do

```
config ENV_VAR_SYM
    string
    option env="ENV_VAR"

source "foo/$ENV_VAR_SYM/Kconfig"
```

(ENV_VAR_SYM could of course be called ENV_VAR as well; I just changed the name to clarify things.)

For another example, see the top-level Kconfig file in the kernel root.

(I'm the author of Kconfiglib [Kconfiglib](https://github.com/ulfalizer/Kconfiglib), a library for working with Kconfig-based configuration systems.)